# How to update variables of ansible roles through jinja2 template

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I am learning ansible roles and I am trying to set the variables of the roles using Jinja2 template. But the variable values are not being updated.

Here's the working directory
sample

```
sample
├── README.md
├── defaults
│   └── main.yml
├── files
│   └── main.out
├── handlers
│   └── main.yml
├── meta
│   └── main.yml
├── tasks
│   └── main.yml
├── templates
│   └── main.j2
├── tests
│   ├── inventory
│   └── test.yml
└── vars
    └── main.yml
```

The contents of the vars/main.yml folder are

```
a: 2
b: 3
c: 0
```

The Contents of the tasks/main.yml are

```
---
 - name: Jagadish Sagi
   template:
           src: "sample2/templates/main.j2"
           dest: "sample2/files/main.out"
 - name: Printing value of c
   debug:
           var: c
```

The Contents of the templates/main.j2 are

```
{% if a > b %}
{% set c = a %}
{% else %}
{% set c = b %}
{% endif %}
The Value of C : {{c}}
```

The Code for executing the role is

```
---
 - hosts: localhost
   roles:
         - sample2
```

In files/main.out file I am getting output

`The Value of C : 3`

But in the ansible playbook while printing it to the console it gives

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "c": 0
}
```

I know that i can do it using ansible only with the help of set_fact and if else conditions. but how can I do it using Jinja2 Template too??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know that i can do it using ansible only with the help of set_fact and if else conditions. but how can I do it using Jinja2 Template too??

You cannot; Jinja2 templates do not mutate their environment, since Jinja2 isn't a programming language, it's template markup.

You must use `set_fact:` to alter the `hostvars` of your playbook run

Answer (score 0):

The `set` you are using in you template will only be valid inside your template. The value of `c` remains unchanged for ansible itself. If you need to use that value later for other tasks, you cannot do it this way.

The [order of precedence](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable) of role vars is still lower than `set_fact` so this could do the trick.

Meanwhile, if `c` is always a calculated var that can change depending on `a` and `b`, this is what I would do.

- declare `a` and `b` in role's default so that they are easily overloaded in any situation

```
---
# defaults/main.yml
a: 2
b: 3
```

- declare `c` in role vars depending on `a` and `b` values

```
---
# vars/main.yml
c: "{{ (a > b) | ternary(a, b) }}"
```

You can now use `c` wherever you like in your tasks with its correct value without having to calculate anything else.